# What is bi-binary code?

Tags: encoding-scheme

This being used in data bits transmitted by GLONASS Satellites. I am sure it is different from other codes like 'Binary Code' which the search engine throws up

Comment: Do you have *any* reference for this term?

Comment: Just a wil guess, but network cards use 01 to represent 0 and 10 to represent 1.

Comment: This [GLONASS ICD](https://www.unavco.org/help/glossary/docs/ICD_GLONASS_5.1_(2008)_en.pdf) document is the reference